# Fixing Windows Update Issue from Windows 10 1709 to Windows 10 1803+

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I am experiencing a problem with windows update.  The install will fail at about 60-70% and roll back to a previous version of windows.  I’ve attached the logs from the latest attempt at an install of update 1803.  It fails with error code 0x800704c7, but I wasn't able to find anything that was particularly useful with that error code that I hadn't already done.

I have already tried the following:

Running the Windows 10 Update Assistant (results in the same problem as running the updates otherwise.

Running Windows Update Troubleshooter and Resolving All Issues before retrying the install.

Downloaded latest Servicing Stack Update

Downloaded the latest KB

Used DISM tool to ensure there was no image of file corruption

Stopped update services and cleared the software distribution folders before retrying the update from scratch.

Update failed again, attached Windows Update Log from the last update.

In all cases, the update runs for a while, gets to about 60-70% with multiple restarts then rolls back.

[Log is in pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/LhaYUNR3)

UPDATE: None of the recommendations helped.  Issue was solved by a a full reinstall of windows (repair, recovery, in place update, etc all did not help).  Three other laptops made from the same image also had this issue, so something got thoroughly broken when they were imaged originally.

Comment: Why upgrade to 1803 and not to 1903? Have you tried offline upgrade?

Comment: @harrymc I have not tried an offline update, that is a good idea and I will try it.  1803 is the version that Windows Update Service keeps grabbing.  I have used the Update assistant tool as well, which should try to update to 1903, and it also fails.

Comment: @harrymc's answer about doing a repair install should fix the issue, but I would try cleaning the component store first, as a dirty component store will prevent Windows' updates: WinSxS cleanup: `dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup`, once done: `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`, reboot if any corruption is found/fixed, then `sfc /scannow`, reboot if any corruption found/fixed, then retry update.  You can also bypass Windows Update altogether via using [Microsoft's](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) update site's Update Now button

Comment: @JW0914 I have previously followed those steps, without success.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus You ran the first command w/ parameter `/startcomponentcleanup`?  If not, the latter two must be re-run in the order listed, as each of the three is sequential, depending on the other. `/StartComponentCleanup` ensures the WinSxS directory [Windows Component Store] is correctly configured for the updates currently installed. `/RestoreHealth` verifies there's no corruption in WinSxS by checking hashes against known good copies via Windows Update - WinSxS contains a backup of all system files. `SFC /ScanNow` verifies all files in `%WinDir%` against the known good copies in WinSxS

Comment: Microsoft Doc: [Manage the Component Store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/manage-the-component-store) explains in more detail about WinSxS (`%WinDir%\WinSxS`) for a better understanding of what it is.

Comment: @JW0914 I believe I ran those commands as you've listed them.  I am now rerunning them to verify just in case I run similar commands but not those specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Update on your computer seems to have a problem accessing the latest version.

I suggest to force the issue by doing offline upgrade to version 1903.

For details see the article
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).